# How to vectorize np.dot between vectors located in arrays of vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

**Variables:**

x and y are arrays of N 2D vectors with shapes (N, 2).

**Question:**

Is there a way to perform the dot product between the vectors corresponding to the same position in the two arrays without explicitly writing the elements as in a list comprehension: `[np.dot(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(N)]` ?

Typically, in other functions in numpy I use the option `axis = 1` in order to achieve this, but I see it does not exist in np.dot. Is there some way to manage to vectorize this operation?

Comment: `(x * y).sum(axis=1)` should do IIUC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
N = 10
x = np.random.randn(N,2)
y = np.random.randn(N,2)

np.einsum("ij,ij->i", x, y)
```

Comment: In my computer and in my particular problem, this answer is a factor 3 faster than `(x * y).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: It's really fast! But I'm not sure whether this could be extended to multithread/multiprocess. This `np.einsum` may not run in parallel, even given `optimize=True`. I saw [discussion](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues/835#issuecomment-796207574) states that similar contraction route is memory bounded, and may not gain speedup for more threads. Could any one verify this statement?